# AutoMapper 6.2.2 Error Mapping Types

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, automapper-6

I'm trying to Map 2 types by using Automapper

```
var userRightInternal =  Mapper.Map<MibUserRight, UserRight>(userRight, 
    dest => dest.ConfigureMap().ForMember(p => p.PricingModel, m => m.Ignore()));
```

But i'm still getting the following error:

> Error Mapping types
>
> Mapping types: MibUserRight -> UserRight GVP.Database.MibUserRight ->
>   TvOpenPlatform.UserRights.Domain.Entities.UserRight
>
> Type Map configuration: MibUserRight -> UserRight
>   GVP.Database.MibUserRight ->
>   TvOpenPlatform.UserRights.Domain.Entities.UserRight
>
> Property: PricingModel

Why is it trying to map, if i'm telling it to ignore?

Comment: Try CreateMap instead.

Comment: CreateMap is from previous vesions of automapper

Comment: No :) Read the docs.